# Change attribute value programmatically

Tags: magento2, database, product-attribute

I have created product programmatically but when i try to update attribute value with code:

```
$product->setData($attributeCode, '')->save();
```

It won't change. The update will work only after i have saved the product in Magento admin GUI. **What might be the reason of that?**

Code I use to create product:

```
  $_product->setName($productName)
    ->setId($productID)
    ->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId)
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setVisibility(4)
    ->setStatus(1)
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) 
    ->setSku($Sku)
    ->setPrice($price)
    ->setDescription($description)
    ->setShortDescription($shortDescription)
    ->setStockData(array(
         'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
         'is_in_stock' => $stock,
         'qty' => $qty
    ))
    ->setUrlKey($urlKey)
    ->setCategoryIds(array($CategoryId))
    ->setTypeId("simple")
    ->setData($attributeCode, 5)
    ->save();
```

Editing script

```
`$_product->load($productID)->setStoreId($storeId)->setData($attributeCode, 'Blue')->save();`
```

`$_product` is an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that may your attribute code isn't correct. You should check the attribute code again: **STORES > Attributes > Product**. You also need to reindex the database and clear your Magento Cache to see the result after updating the attribute.

Comment: How is it possible that when i am creating the product all seems to be ok and the attribute appears in the right place? The problem is about updating the attribute value.

Comment: You created new product via php script also?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Please, update your question again with the scripts for creating and editing?

Comment: Please, update your all code lines on your question above, that because it's easy for community following your question.

Comment: You created two separate files or one file for creating and editing?

Comment: Two separate files that is called by if sentence that checks if product exists. My problem is that the attribute field updates only after i have saved product manually in GUI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45184/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-user3748173).